# Meteor's Iron Router: get query parameter on both Client and Server Side

Tags: node.js, meteor, query-string, iron-router

there

In my application, if someone pass a parameter on the URL I want to do different things on the template.

I know I can get on server side a query string using `this.params.query` but how can I pass it to client OR get this value on client-side?

In my case I will send an optional `redirect` on the URL, and if it was passed, after the main task, my app will redirect the user to the url given. But I just know how to see `redirect` on server side, not on client, so this information get lost when I, for example, submit a form

Could you help me?

Answer (score 1):

You can access the router params in your template with:

```
Router.current().params.query
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in your route you can do like this:

```
onBeforeAction: function() {
    Session.set("query", this.params.query);
    this.next();
},
```

Then somewhere on the client you can make a helper like this:

```
Template.yourTemplateName.helpers({
  query: function() {
    return Session.get("query");
  }
});
```

I'm not sure what to do with your redirect, but maybe it will work in the helper. So your html would be something like:

```
{{#if query}}{{query}}{{/if}}
```

And in the helper you could possibly replace "return Session.get("query")" with something like "Router.go('/wherever-you-want-to-go');". Or just write another helper to run in your html if the query is positive.

Comment: hey there. I have a question: i am defining a function as a `Router.route` parameter. I am passing it as the second parameter, and the path if the first. I suppose I have to add `onBeforeAction` as the key of an object, right? but what about everything I already have inside the function that I'm already using? Where does it go? passing a function is the same as registering a default hook?

Comment: The code in the before hook only sets the session value to your parameter so it can be retrieved when you need it. It doesn't actually perform anything. I'm not entirely following what you want to do here. Maybe if you could be more specific ... I'm ok at solving problems, but bad at talking the talk.